# Test that a click event in React updates the HTML

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, reactjs

I've set up some tests of a React component that displays a table using Mocha. I can assert on its initial state but I have a click event which sorts the data that I'd like to test.

If I use `React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.click(theComponent)` to try to test the sort.

- I can see that the event is handled,
- that the state change is fired
- the data is sorted before calling `setState`

but when I assert against the component nothing has changed.

```
it('sorts the data when the year header is clicked', function() {
    var React = require('react/addons');
    var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

    var payTable = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <PayTable payYears={data} />
    );

    var headers = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(payTable, 'th');
    var yearHeader = headers[0];
    TestUtils.Simulate.click(yearHeader.getDOMNode());

    var columnValues = getYearColumnValues(payTable, TestUtils);
    columnValues.should.match([ 'Year', '1066', '1067', '1068' ]);
});
```

Do I need to force an update? Re-read the component?

The code is available [on Github](https://github.com/pauldambra/reactotype/blob/cf3bc8d57aea46bb1945852d560fe2b403617407/tests/payTableSpec.js).

I can test other aspects of the Component but not the Component values after `setState`

Comment: If you are using Mocha to test DOM changes you could use mochify to help. I wrote an example on the wiki on how to test ReactJS components which may be of help: https://github.com/mantoni/mochify.js/wiki/Testing-a-ReactJS-Component-with-Mochify

Comment: If you don't want to use the setTimeout hack, or another library. Try creating callbacks for your events. Such as YearHeaderSelected or similar on Paytable. You can then pass that in and respond to it in your test

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. The thing is, `TestUtils.Simulate.click(yearHeader.getDOMNode())` is making a click on the DOM, which brings about sorting data and DOM manipulation. Even if you use jsDom and not a real dom, this manipulation itself is an *async* event. So, just by checking the DOM state right after the click event you are making a syncronous call, within which the DOM state has not been changed yet.

The solution is, use a `setTimeout` with 0 milliseconds timeout, and check the DOM state there. As for you example :

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var columnValues = getYearColumnValues(payTable, TestUtils);
  columnValues.should.match([ 'Year', '1066', '1067', '1068' ]);
},0)
```

This would make your DOM update its state and you will be able to test your component.

Comment: setTimeout in this situation is a hack. This is a poor solution

Comment: yes it is a hack, unfortunately I have not yet found an alternative solution to this issue

Comment: How about using `setImmediate()` for this purpose? Since it queues the action after everything else it seems to be a good fit?

Comment: haven't tried it, might work. had TestUtils.Simulate.click have returned a promise, or provided a callback api, things would have been much easier

Comment: @KoustuvSinha I'm stuck in a similar situation. Could we find a solution to this?

Comment: @ChiragMongia for now the hacky solution is all I have. if you find a better alternative do post here!

Comment: I can't get this to work. I'm doing almost exactly the same as the OP, but in setTimeout, the HTML hasn't updated at all and it never calls `render()` again after the click.

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick for me too (using sinon's FakeXMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

I've been spending a lot of time trying to find a clean way to work with the asynchronousity... Ended up making this for testing:

https://github.com/yormi/test-them-all

Under the hood, it uses `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle to listen on props/state/route changes.

Hopefully, it'll help you guys. Anyhow your opinion would be greatly appreciated :)